# Subtracting from a date in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm having big problems doing operation with the date in Excel VBA.
I have a form that has a textbox where the user will enter the date. The problem is that he may enter it in different formats (eg, 1.08.2011 for 1st of August, or 8/1/11 for the same day). Now what I want to do is to subtract some days from that date that he enters in the TextBox. I had to success so far and I don't know how to do it.
I tried something like this

```
Format((Format(Me.datalivrare.Value, "dd.mm.yyy") - 4), "dd.mm.yyyy")
```

Where datalivrare is that textbox where the user enters the date and 4 is the number of days I want to subtract from that date... and I want the format to always be dd.mm.yyyy no matter what they enter in that textbox.

Comment: How do you distinguish whether 8/1/11 means 1st of August or 8th of January?

Comment: CDate it, it will assume your location context

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I suggest looking at the DateAdd function for VBA

http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/dateadd.php

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/dateadd-function-HA001228810.aspx

You could do the following:

```
Format(DateAdd("d", -4, CDate(Me.datalivrare.Value)), "dd.mm.yyyy")
```

Answer (score 7):

First cast to Date, then subtract days, then format appropriately:

```
Format(DateAdd("d", -4, CDate(Me.datalivrare.Value)), "dd.mm.yyyy")
```

Answer (score 6):

the best to add and substract from dates on vba is [dateadd()](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/dateadd-function-HA001228810.aspx) (with negative number for substractions)
also, in your example code there's a missing y on the format string (it accepts 1, 2 or 4 y, only)

Comment: on the other way, i'd recomend restricting the user input to a known format with a masked textbox if possible, or simply data validation

Answer (score 1):

It is important to check if the user entered a value that VBA can interprit as a date so first you should:

```
If isDate(Me.datalivrare.Value) Then
    str_Date = Format(DateAdd("d", -4, CDate(Me.datalivrare.Value)), "dd.mm.yyyy")
Else
    MsgBox "Not a valid date value", vbCritical + vbOkOnly, "Invalid Entry"
End If
```

I think bluefeet's answer had the most information so far and I borrowed the use of DateAdd and CDate.

Answer (score 0):

Just a simple answer, as many aren't using the OP's code.

Eg: Minus 4 days

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/dateadd-function

```
Sub DateTest()
 Dim DateVar As Date
 DateVar = DateAdd("d", -4, Date)
 Debug.Print DateVar
End Sub
```