# Format() a Date

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to `Format` a `Date`.  That `Date` will always be from a week ago.  What I've tried is:

```
filename = Format(Date - (Weekday(Date) - 7) + 3, "mm-dd-yy")
```

But I get a Compile error: Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment.  I'm not sure what the +3 means exactly as I didn't write this line, but I'm waiting on a response for that question.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: I encourage you to look here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6986940/subtracting-from-a-date-in-vba the best answer here should help you.

Comment: Runs for me just fine, gives the result of "06-09-15". What is the filename variable? What do you intend to do with it?

Comment: `FileName` is a member of both the Worksheet and Workbook classes. Are you running this from Worksheet or Workbook code modules?

Comment: @Cptn_Hammer thank you.  DateAdd() helps though I still get an error from the amount of arguments for Format()

Comment: If you do `Format(DateAdd("d", -7, CDate(Me.date.Value)), "mm-dd-yy")`?

Comment: @vacip the filename is a String.  And I'm trying filename = Format(DateAdd("ww", -1, Date), "mm-dd-yy") and still getting errors.

Comment: @Cptn_Hammer I don't know what the CDate stuff is but that also gives me an error of "Invalid use of Me keyword"

Comment: Sure, the me.date would be if you had a userform with a value called date. Instead, you'd want to use now(), so you get `Format(DateAdd("d", -7, now()), "mm-dd-yy")`

Comment: @Cptn_Hammer alrighty I'm trying this now:                                        |||||||||   filedate = DateAdd("d", -7, Now())
|||||||||                               filename = Format(filedate, "mm-dd-yy")                                                    but I still get the arguments error for the Format()

Comment: How are you declaring filedate?

Answer (score 0):

I'll expand my comment above: 
Typically in VB, if you can't understand something, you're probably making it too complicated :p

You can avoid the (rather gross) date subtraction / +3 code you have above and increase readability by using `now()`.

try this:
`Format(DateAdd("d", -7, now()), "mm-dd-yy")`

What this does is this:
`now()` is of course, the current date.

`DateAdd("d",-7,now())` will do what you want, go back a week from the current date (by subtracting 7 days. `DateAdd()` should take care of pesky calendar months)

Wrapping this in a `Format()` will just format the date how you want, namely "mm-dd-yy"

Hope this helps,

-Cptn

See [Formatting dates in VBA](http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/format_date.php)

Comment: Dim filedate As String
    and    Dim filename As String

Comment: Try dim filedate as Date and see if that solves the problem you had above, or simply use your string `filename = Format(DateAdd("d", -7, now()), "mm-dd-yy")`

It should also be noted that date() will give you today's date, where as now() will give you the date and time.

Comment: Okay I'm back to just one line again: filename = Format(DateAdd("d", -7, Now()), "mm-dd-yy")  and still getting the #arguments or invalid property error.  How did you go about checking the code?

Comment: Okay wow.  Someone else had an overriding Format() on this machine.  So that's fixed.  Now I just get something for the AddDate() that says "Sub or Function not defined".  Got anything for that?

Comment: DateAdd(), not addDate() [Documentation](http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/dateadd.php)